# Fetch data from array and pass from widget to activity without listview

Tags: java, android, android-widget, android-pendingintent, android-appwidget

`Listview` is scrollable therefore it doesn't match parent by dynamically resizing its rows. Is it possible to get the data from array and pass them to activity individually so I can use `LinearLayout` instead?

```
RemoteViews mainView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main_widget_layout);
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        RemoteViews textView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.text_append_layout);
        textView.setTextViewText(R.id.appending_text, String.valueOf(i));
        mainView.addView(R.id.text_data_viewer, textView);

        Intent fillInIntent = new Intent();
        fillInIntent.putExtra("extradata", i);
        textView.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.appending_text, fillInIntent);
    }
Intent activitytoStart = new Intent(context, Widget.class).setAction("com.custom.action");
mainView.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.text_data_viewer, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, activitytoStart, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

**main_widget_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/text_data_viewer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:weightSum="16"
                android:orientation="vertical"/>
```

**text_append_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/appending_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

Comment: No one is helping at all. Fellow members were really helpful few months back.

Answer (score 0):

First off why are you not using a remoteviewsfactory? that will make filling a listview so much easier.

but to answer your question - to pass data from widget to activity you will need to pass it in intents, so when you click on the widget it opens the activity.
setup the widget with pending intent:

```
        Intent clickIntentTemplate = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

        clickIntentTemplate.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        clickIntentTemplate.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        clickIntentTemplate.putExtra("extraName",extra);
        clickIntentTemplate.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        PendingIntent configPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, clickIntentTemplate, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_view, configPendingIntent);
```

Retrieve intent in activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        String retrievedString = getIntent().getExtras().getString("extraName");
    }
    //...rest of your code
}
```

Also include the method in your onNewIntent():

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        String retrievedString = getIntent().getExtras().getString("extraName");
    }
}
```